# Beaglebone Black Ground Bounce on SPI at 48mhz

Tags: beagleboneblack, spi

Is there an appropriate method for using SPI at the full 48mhz without introducing ground bouncing?

I have a c script that uses SPI on the BeagleBone connected to an ADC. I need to acquire as close to 1msps from the ADC, and subsequentially need more than 48mhz, but 48mhz will work for now.

When the SPI CLK starts, the SPI and GPIO's experience a noticeable ground bounce that is leaking over into my ADC. I've read this is because of the fast clock switching to create the CLK pulses.

I've tried SPI0 and SPI1 to eliminate there being any hardware issues as mentioned in the solution here: [Cannot configure SPI0 on BeagleBone Green Wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620504/cannot-configure-spi0-on-beaglebone-green-wireless)

[image: scope of ground bounce from beaglebone spi]

I'm using this library https://github.com/VegetableAvenger/BBBIOlib

```
BBBIO_McSPI_channel_ctrl(BBBIO_McSPI_SPI0,
      BBBIO_McSPI_CH0,
      BBBIO_McSPI_Master,
      BBBIO_McSPI_Rx_Only,
      BBBIO_McSPI_CLDIV_1,    /* 48Mhz div XX as SPI speed */
      BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_MODE1,
      BBBIO_McSPI_EN_ACT_LOW, /* CS/En pin low when active */
      BBBIO_McSPI_D0I_D1I,    /* data0 & 1 input */
      16);  /* 16 bit TxRx per work */
```